# Regex для файла с расширением

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Есть файлы, которые имеют формат названия `*цифра*.bmp` и `*цифра*_a.bmp`. Нужно составить regex, что бы их "отлавливать". В названиях присутствуют как цифры, так и числа (двухзначные). Пробовал `\d.bmp|\d\d.bmp`, но не получается их отсеить.

Comment: Отлавливать нужно файлы с именем без букв, то есть `*цифра*.bmp`

Comment: Путь к файлу полный или только имя и расширение имеете?

Comment: По сути тут вовсе можно обойтись таким подходом: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"file.bmp").All(char.IsDigit)`, результатом будет true (если название только из цифр) и false (если есть буквы).

Comment: `\d{1,2}\.bmp` должно помочь(точку забыли отразить еще)

Comment: @Buka, к сожалению не подошло. Я беру файлы из ресурсов, поэтому они идут с `_` перед именем, может в этом причина? Я переделал regex под `_\d{1,2}\.bmp`, но это не помогло

Comment: @Irvin а в отладке какие имена у файлов и какие именно не подошли

Comment: @Buka https://ibb.co/T4pZyMP Мне нужно добавить в список файлы только с цифрой, а файлы с "_a" пропустить (Похоже, что расширение здесь не учитывается)

Comment: @Irvin а там же нет расширения bmp, вот `_\d{1,2}$` должен подойти

Comment: @Buka Все равно не получилось. Вот код который за это отвечает: https://ibb.co/3yPRf1X

Comment: @Irvin в `q_pattern` должно содержаться название файла а в конструкторе regex тот самый паттерн `_\d{1,2}$`

Comment: @Buka Это помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для исключительно цифрового имени:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"file.bmp").All(char.IsDigit)
```

> спасибо EvgeniyZ

или регекс:

```
\d{1,}.bmp
```

---

для имени Nцифр_a.bmp

```
\d{1,}_a.bmp
```